# can I call my own local service from another website?

Tags: security, web, browser, cors

Lets say I build a website and am letting it run on localhost:8080. You would think that this would make it inaccessible to the web. right? However isn't it possible as I am browsing the web, to download some javascript which in turn, makes a request to my localhost:8080 takes that data, then posts it to another site? I'm wondering it this is an attack vector I should worry about (assuming cors is permissive on the local service).

Comment: What you're describing is exactly how things like Dell's ServiceTag utility, or MS's "Sign-in Assistant" (from around 2005) worked. And yes, there is a security _risk_ (but not necessarily a vulnerability). The most obvious risk is fingerprinting, ofc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a different website *could* cause your browser to make local requests or requests to your local network.